# Each solution of $\dot{x} = f(x)$ is strictely monotone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems proving the following little statement:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Each solution (as long as there exist solutions) of the differential equation 
\begin{align}
\dot{x} = f(x) 
\end{align}
is strictely monotone.

I don't really know how to start proving this. Hence, I would be thankful for any little hint on a purposeful approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x) \neq 0$ means either $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, or $f(x) < 0$ for all $x$.

In the first case, we then have
$$
\dot{x} = f(x) > 0,
$$
which means that a solution $x(t)$ of this differential equation is strictly increasing with $t$.

Comment: Because a discontinuous $f(x)$ can give problems with the existence of solutions, and also can be nonzero, yet not of the same sign everywhere; e.g., let $f(x) = -1$ for $x < 1$, and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 1$.